# tableView:editActionsForRowAt: on right-swipe?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

As I was using *tableView:editActionsForRowAt:* to provide some useful functionalities in an iOS app.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    print(#function)
    .... useful code .....
}
```

I got to the point where some other API similar to the one above, but fired on a right swipe, rather than left swipe like *tableView:editActionsForRowAt:* would have been useful. Say something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               editMoreActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    print(#function)
    .... useful code .....
}
```

Browsing the net I found those two methods of the UITableViewDelegate protocol:

```
tableView:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt
tableView:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt
```

After some basic experimentation, I thought I could get what I wanted, using *tableView:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt*, so providing some more functionalities to the user on the right swipe of a cell. But it seems like this method doesn't give much freedom. For example, here the code I have (very much inspired by some sample I found on the internet):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt 
               indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil, handler: {
        (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
        print("Update action ...")
        success(true)
    })

    modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "MyNiceIcon")!.withColor(color: .black)
    modifyAction.backgroundColor = .clear

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [modifyAction])
}
```

Here even though these lines are present:

```
modifyAction.image = UIImage(named: "MyNiceIcon")!.withColor(color: .black)
modifyAction.backgroundColor = .clear
```

MyNiceIcon stays white and the background of the button is gray.

Am I missing something? Or can the color of the image used only be white?
And the background color never transparent?

Comment: [Maybe MGSwipeTableCell can help?](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=MGSwipeTableViewCell&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Yes, and if this sounds too complicated, I may as well just "be happy" with what 
tableView:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt lets me doing.

Comment: @Michel have you tried something like `withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` on UIImage and then changing the colour ?

Comment: No, it was too many problems for something not so important. I just to what I need with what tableView:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt allows me do do and that's OK.

Answer (score 1):

To set original image in action you can create custom class of `UIImage` and override method `withRenderingMode` as follow

```
class OriginalImageRender: UIImage {
    override func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) -> UIImage {
        return self
    }
}
```

To use:

```
if let cgImageX =  UIImage(named: "MyNiceIcon")?.cgImage {
    modifyAction.image = OriginalImageRender(cgImage: cgImageX, scale: UIScreen.main.nativeScale, orientation: .up)
}
```

Above code will display image as original which added inside image assets.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you. You can set the background color of any swipe action plus you can even create a few of them on one swipe. Simple example would be using something like this:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = deleteAction(at: indexPath)

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
}

   @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    private func deleteAction(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
            let confirmDeletionAC = UIAlertController(title: "Delete", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let confirmAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                self.deleteObject(at: indexPath)
                self.historicTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                //                print("SWIPED TO DELETE")
                completion(true)
            })
            let cancelAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
                //                print("DELETE CANCELLED")
                completion(false)
            })
            confirmDeletionAC.addAction(cancelAlertAction)
            confirmDeletionAC.addAction(confirmAlertAction)
            self.present(confirmDeletionAC, animated: true)
        }

        action.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatWatermelon

        return action
    }
```

This code comes from one of my projects and allows me to set a delete action from the right. If you want an action to come from the left simply use the same function but with `leadingSwipeActionConfigurationForRowAt` where you return the UISwipeActionsConfiguration, you use an array of UIContextualAction elements.

Answer (score 0):

1- just add this class at the end of your class

```
class OriginalImageRender: UIImage {
override func withRenderingMode(_ renderingMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) -> UIImage {
    return self
}
```

}
2- create a cgImage from your UIImage

```
let cgImageX =  UIImage(named: "delete")?.cgImage
```

3- pass this cgImage to class OriginalImageRender and add this image to your action

```
 action.image = OriginalImageRender(cgImage: cgImageX!)
```

It Worked for me, Hope helpful to you